# Dict not loading as expected

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some ordered Dicts that are saved as .pkl, In my code I test if the .pkl files exist, then load them, if not create them.

My issue is if they already exist and have data I would expect the `print('Number of files in Dict: %s'%len(Dict)` in `checkRunComplete(Dict)` to give a number but it gives 0 instead.

```
duplicates_dict = OrderedDict() 

runDict = OrderedDict() 

csvDict = OrderedDict() 

rawDict = OrderedDict() 



def polling():
    try:
        while True:
            createPickle(duplicates_dict, runDict, csvDict, rawDict)
            checkRunComplete(runDict)
            checkRunComplete(csvDict)
            checkRunComplete(rawDict)
            time.sleep(2)
 

def checkRunComplete(Dict):
    print('Number of files in Dict: %s'%len(Dict)
    for I,k in zip(Dict.keys()[0::2], Dict.keys()[1::2]):
        lookForFiles(Dict,i,k)


def createPickle(duplicates_dict, runDict, csvDict, rawDict):

    os.chdir(Duplicate_Files)

    if not os.path.isfile(Duplicate_Files+filename):

        print('Duplicates_Dict Created')

        with open(filename, 'wb') as handle:

            pickle.dump(duplicates_dict, handle)

        handle.close()


    if not os.path.isfile(Duplicate_Files+runName):

        print('runDict Created')

        with open(runName, 'wb') as rn:

            pickle.dump(runDict, rn)

        rn.close()


    if not os.path.isfile(Duplicate_Files+csvName):

        print('csvDict Created')

        with open(csvName, 'wb') as cn:

            pickle.dump(csvDict, cn)

        cn.close()



    if not os.path.isfile(Duplicate_Files+rawName):

        print('rawDict Created')

        with open(rawName, 'wb') as rawn:

            pickle.dump(rawDict, rawn)

        rawn.close()

   

    else:
        loadDicts(duplicates_dict, runDict, csvDict, rawDict)

   
  

def loadDicts(duplicates_dict, runDict, csvDict, rawDict):

    with open(Duplicate_Files+filename, 'rb') as handle:

        duplicates_dict = pickle.load(handle)

    handle.close() 



    with open(Duplicate_Files+runName, 'rb') as rn:

        runDict = pickle.load(rn)

    rn.close()



    with open(Duplicate_Files+csvName, 'rb') as cn:

        csvDict = pickle.load(cn)

    cn.close()



    with open(Duplicate_Files+rawName, 'rb') as rawn:

        rawDict = pickle.load(rawn)

    rawn.close()

    print('All Dicts Exsit and are loaded')





def main():

    Polling()


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just did the following under the declared Dicts:

```
try:
    with open(Duplicate_Files+RunName, 'rb') as rn:
        runDict = picle.load(rn)
    rn.close()
except IOError:
    pass
```